# good style in lisp: cons vs list

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

Is it good style to use cons for pairs of things or would it be preferable to stick to lists?

like for instance questions and answers:

```
(list
    (cons
        "Favorite color?"
        "red")
    (cons
        "Favorite number?"
        "123")
    (cons
        "Favorite fruit?"
        "avocado"))
```

I mean, some things come naturally in pairs; there is no need for something that can hold more than two, so I feel like cons would be the natural choice. However, I also feel like I should be sticking to one thing (lists).

What would be the better or more accepted style?

Comment: The only possible reason not to use cons where appropriate is to make it easier to port your code to the inferior Lisp dialects which lack cons cells altogether (e.g., Clojure).

Comment: Check out Google Common Lisp Style Guide #Data Representation part: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lispguide.xml#Data_Representation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is an [association list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) (alist). Alist entries are, indeed, often simple conses rather than lists (though that is a matter of preference: some people use lists for alist entries too), so what you have is fine. Though, I usually prefer to use literal syntax:

```
'(("Favorite color?" . "red")
  ("Favorite number?" . "123")
  ("Favorite fruit?" . "avocado"))
```

Alists usually use a symbol as the key, because symbols are interned, and so symbol alists can be looked up using [`assq`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_434) instead of [`assoc`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_438). Here's how it might look:

```
'((color . "red")
  (number . "123")
  (fruit . "avocado"))
```

Comment: Not in Common Lisp. There is no `assq` function, and `assoc` defaults to `eql`, but takes keyword arguments `key` to specify an accessor to use instead of identity, and `test`/`test-not` to specify an equivalence function. Using `eq` instead of the default `eql` doesn't really buy much, and breaks for integers in implementation-specific ways.

Comment: @Kaz I'm a Schemer, so clearly can't speak for CL (the question is tagged for both, so I figured either one would do). The question is, does `eql` compare strings correctly? Certainly, in Scheme, `eqv?` will not compare strings the way people tend to expect. Hence the recommendation to use symbols (as opposed to strings) as alist keys is still generally correct.

Comment: No, `eql` does not compare strings; it's an extension of `eq` style equality: for most objects it is "implementation equality", but distinct instances of the same number are eql. (eql 1 1) -> t, (eql 1 1.0) -> nil. Your recommendations are sound for Scheme.

Comment: @Kaz Right, so `eql` is analogous to `eqv?` in Scheme. In fact, there's an `assv` procedure in Scheme, useful for alists keyed by numbers or characters. (`assoc` in Scheme uses `equal?` by default, which is too heavyweight for most alists.)

Answer (score 3):

The default data-structure for such case should be a `HASH-TABLE`.

An association list of cons pairs is also a possible variant and was widely used historically. It is a valid variant, because of tradition and simplicity. But you should not use it, when the number of pairs exceeds several (probably, 10 is a good threshold), because search time is linear, while in hash-table it is constant.

Using a list for this task is also possible, but will be both ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to decide for yourself based upon circumstances. There isn't a universal answer. Different tasks work differently with structures. Consider the following:

- It is faster to search in a hash-table for keys, then it is in the alist.
- It is easier to have an iterator and save its state, when working with alist (hash-table would need to export all of its keys as an array or a list and have a pointer into that list, while it is enough to only remember the pointer into alist to be able to restore the iterator's state and continue the iteration.
- Alist vs list: they use the same amount of conses for even number of elements, given all other characters are atoms. When using lists vs alists you would have to thus make sure there isn't an odd number of elements (and you may discover it too late), which is bad.
- But there are a lot more functions, including the built-in ones, which work on proper lists, and don't work on alists. For example, `nth` will error on alist, if it hits the `cdr`, which is not a `list`.
- Some times certain macros would not function as you'd like them to with alists, for example, this:

---

```
(destructuring-bind (a b c d) 
  '((100 . 200) (300 . 400)) 
   (format t "~&~{~s~^,~}" (list a b c d)))
```

will not work as you might've expected.

- On the other hand, certain procedures may be "tricked" into doing something which they don't do for proper lists. For instance, when copying an alist with copy-list, only the conses, whose `cdr` is a `list` will be copied anew (depending upon the circumstances this may be a desired result).